# One way ANOVA for every column

Tags: r, loops, anova

I need to run a one way ANOVA on every column in a data frame based on another column. My data frame has 57 columns, so it is very time consuming to type out every column name. Here is part of my data frame.

[image]

So basically, I need this function run for every column

```
aov(df$PGY_16 ~ df$Total_Time_cm_16, df)
```

So I need a loop to run that for every column in my data frame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: a simple `lapply` should do.

Answer (score 5):

For reproducibility, the code below uses the built-in `mtcars` data frame and returns a list in which each list element is an `aov` model of `mtcars$cyl` with every other column in the data frame. We use `map` from the `purrr` package (which is part of the `tidyverse` suite of packages) to take care of successively running `aov` on each column of the data frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

aov.models = mtcars[ , -grep("cyl", names(mtcars))] %>%
  map(~ aov(mtcars$cyl ~ .x))
```

For your data, the analogous code would be:

```
aov.models = df[ , -grep("PGY_16", names(df))] %>%
  map(~ aov(df$PGY_16 ~ .x))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this answer. How does one extract results from all these aov.models in a dataframe and how do we do a pvalue adjustment for the same?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without installing `tidyverse` package.
This is the example for `mtcars` data frame.

```
aov.models <- lapply(setdiff(names(mtcars), "cyl"), function(s) {
  aov(as.formula(paste(s, " ~ cyl")),mtcars)
})
```