# iterate dependent variable using purrr and map (tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a simple dataset that I want to iterate the dependent variable using `aov` and `tidyverse`.   From those outputs I then want to compute `Tukey HSD` tests.  I have this working in a for loop structure, but am trying my hardest to migrate from that mentality. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836076/one-way-anova-for-every-column) on iterating `aov`functions with the independent variables.  Tried to incorporate this logic into my workflow, but not working out so well.   Any `tidyverse` aficionados that could steer me in the right direction here?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

pfuel <- fread("data/CFL.csv") %>%
  mutate(AFCL = AFCL*10,
         LCW = LCW*10,
         DCW = DCW*10,
         LiDe = ifelse(Status == "Li", "Live", "Dead")) %>%
  filter(S.F == "S") %>%
  group_by(Site, Year, Age, Plot) %>%
  select(LiFol, DeFol, Li.1hr, De.1hr, Li.10hr, De.10hr, Li.100hr, De.100hr) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(sb_age = paste0(Year, Age))

aov.models = pfuel %>%
  select (-c(Year, Age)) %>%
  select(LiFol, DeFol, Li.1hr, De.1hr, Li.10hr, De.10hr, Li.100hr, De.100hr, Site, Plot, sb_age) %>%
  map(~ aov(.x ~ sb_age + Site/Plot, data = pfuel))
```

When the `aov.models` runs I generate this error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning message:
In model.response(mf, "numeric") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I haven't gotten to the Tukey test yet, as I cannot get past the aov function.  Any suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated!

You can find the data here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yb8rh860fc7fff2/CFL.csv?dl=0

Thanks!

Comment: My first red flag would be `pfuel$...` - I'm pretty sure you don't want to be referencing anything using `pfuel$` really when `aov(formula, data=.)` or some similar construction could be used.

Comment: I'm also unclear why you do two separate `select()` statements. If one is excluding certain variables, but then you just select a specified list, why bother with the initial exclusion?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Still getting the same error though.  I have added the error to the main question.  Thanks

Comment: The select comment is a good one - thank you! Not sure, made sense at the time.

Comment: The error is suggesting it is falling over because you have `NA` or `NaN` variables in the variable you are trying to predict.

Comment: But the `pfuel` object doesn't contain any `NA` or `NaN` values...

Comment: `Site` & `sb_age` are character strings rather than numerical values. When you specify them on the LHS of the aov formula, they get coerced to numeric & throw out NAs in protest. Drop them from the `select()` call & your code should work.

Comment: @Z.Lin but those variables make up the entire suite of independent variables, and this equation works fine outside of `map`.  For instance, if I do `t <- aov(LiFol ~ sb_age + Site/Plot, data = pfuel)` I get an output I would expect without any errors.

Comment: Go down the list of all the variables in your `select()` call. When you reach `aov(Site~ sb_age + Site/Plot, data = pfuel)` & `aov(sb_age ~ sb_age + Site/Plot, data = pfuel)`, do you still get output without error?

Comment: @Z.Lin ok, you're right.  Point understood.  An error gets thrown then, but how do I solve the map issue?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to convert the data to long form, split by response, then fit models and feed the output to the `HSD.test` function, e.g.,

```
aov.models <- pfuel %>%
  select(-Year, -Age) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -sb_age, -Site, -Plot) %>%
  split(.$variable) %>%
  map(~ aov(value ~ sb_age + Site/Plot, data = .x)) %>%
  map(HSD.test, trt = 'sb_age')
```

I also removed one of the `select()` statements, as it was selecting all of the columns.

Comment: Thanks, Max! Works like a dream. Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

@Z.Lin  With your guidance I figured out a solution to the first part of my question.  Probably not the most elegant, but it is at least working now! Any refinement would be welcomed, but thank you.

```
pfuel_var <- pfuel %>%
  select(Site, Plot, sb_age) %>%
  mutate(Site = as.factor(Site),
         Plot = as.factor( Plot),
         sb_age = as.factor(sb_age))

aov.models <- pfuel %>%
  select(LiFol, DeFol, Li.1hr, De.1hr, Li.10hr, De.10hr, Li.100hr, De.100hr) %>%
  map(~ aov(.x ~ pfuel_var$sb_age + pfuel_var$Site/pfuel_var$Plot, data = pfuel))
```

The second part of my question was how to feed this output into `HSD.test` from the `agricolae` package.  Anyone have thoughts on that?

What I was thinking would be:

```
t <- aov.models %>% 
   map(~ HSD.test(.x, "pfuel_var$sb_age", alpha=0.1))
```

But that is not working properly. Thoughts very much appreciated.

Comment: Because you are using `data = pfuel` in `aov` (and not the dataset of only the "selected" columns), you can *not* select the three explanatory variables in `select` but still use them in your model without the dollar sign notation.